# How to get variable outside event listener in a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I would like to return the new value for count so that the while statement below can change the text of a label. Everything else but this works.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.applet.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class beepBoop extends JApplet { 

    private JButton play = new JButton("Play");
    private JButton loop = new JButton("Loop");
    private JButton stop = new JButton("Stop");
    JLabel songTitle = new JLabel("Test");
    JLabel amountClicks = new JLabel();
    JLabel warning = new JLabel("KEEP ON LISTENING!!!");
    private AudioClip audioClip;

    int count = 0;

    public beepBoop() {

        audioClip = Applet.newAudioClip(getClass().getResource("song1.wav"));
        JPanel pane = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(play);
        panel.add(loop);
        panel.add(stop);
        panel.add(songTitle);
        panel.add(amountClicks);
        panel.add(warning);
        stop.setEnabled(false);
        add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);


        play.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    start();
                    songTitle.setText("LOVE THE SONG");
                    count++;
                    amountClicks.setText("You have pressed button " + count + " times.");
                }
        });
        loop.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    loop();
                    songTitle.setText("YOU REALLY LOVE THIS SONG");
                }
        });
        stop.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    stop();
                    songTitle.setText("WOW YOU ALREADY QUIT IT!!!");
                }
        });
        int countTotal = count;

        while (countTotal >= 5) {
            if (countTotal >= 5) {
                warning.setText("MAYBE YOU'VE HAD TOO MUCH!!!");
            } else if (countTotal >= 10) {
                warning.setText("YOU HAVE HAD WAYYY TO MUCH!!!");
            } else {
                warning.setText("WOW!!!");
            }
        }

    }

    public void start() {

        audioClip.play();
        play.setEnabled(false);
        stop.setEnabled(true);
        loop.setEnabled(true);       
    }

    public void loop() {
        stop();
        audioClip.loop();
        loop.setEnabled(false);
        play.setEnabled(true); 
        stop.setEnabled(true);
    }    

    public void stop() {
        audioClip.stop();
        stop.setEnabled(false);
        loop.setEnabled(true);
        play.setEnabled(true);        
    }    

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        beepBoop player = new beepBoop();

         JFrame frame = new JFrame("beepBoop");
         beepBoop applet = new beepBoop();
        applet.init();

        frame.getContentPane().add(applet, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.setSize(225,275);
        frame.setVisible(true);       
    }
}
```

So to recap all i would like to do is get the variable outside of play.addActionListener so that the while statement below can show the correct respond after an amount of clicks have been triggered.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) At a glance it seems this code is going into an infinite loop and blocking the EDT. Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).  The GUI will 'freeze' when that happens.  See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for details and the fix.

Comment: .. 3) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would like to return the new value for count so that the while statement below can change the text of a label.

No, you really don't. Seriously. This code:

```
    while (countTotal >= 5) {
        if (countTotal >= 5) {
            warning.setText("MAYBE YOU'VE HAD TOO MUCH!!!");
        } else if (countTotal >= 10) {
            warning.setText("YOU HAVE HAD WAYYY TO MUCH!!!");
        } else {
            warning.setText("WOW!!!");
        }
    }
```

belongs in a linear user interface console program, one where you know precisely when the code flow will go into this loop, and when it does, it must stay in the loop until the user is done entering data.

But that's not how Swing (or any event-driven paradigm-using) programs work, since with event-driven code, you don't have full control over program flow, since the user has the liberty of interacting with any GUI component that is presented to him and is enabled.

So instead perhaps you wish to use the counter variable in one of your ActionListeners, and **change the listener's behavior depending on the state of the counter variable**. An if/else or switch block could work for this.

So, perhaps,....

```
play.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            start();
            songTitle.setText("LOVE THE SONG");
            count++;
            amountClicks.setText("You have pressed button " + count + " times.");

            if (countTotal >= 5) {
                warning.setText("MAYBE YOU'VE HAD TOO MUCH!!!");
            } else if (countTotal >= 10) {
                warning.setText("YOU HAVE HAD WAYYY TO MUCH!!!");
            } else {
                warning.setText("WOW!!!");
            }
        }
});
```

Comment: Thank You :D and I had not known that before about GUI's I'm kinda new to this so thank you for the incite.